# How to share files in dropbox api using node.js

Tags: node.js, dropbox-api

I want to share uploaded files in dropbox with another member.

```
add_member={
  method: "POST",
  url:'https://api.dropboxapi.com/2/sharing/add_file_member',
  headers:{
    "content-Type":"application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + access_token,
    "Data":"{\"file\": \"id:3kmLmQFnf1AAAAAAAAAAAw\",\"members\": [{\".tag\": \"email\",\"email\": \"jyotijagtap2209@gmail.com\"}],\"custom_message\": \"This is a custom message about ACME.doc\",\"quiet\": false,\"access_level\": \"viewer\",\"add_message_as_comment\": false}"
  },
  body:content
}

request(add_member,function(err,res,body){
  console.log("link shared", body);
})
```

This is my code. I have also read documentation for Dropbox API but I can't get what is **id** given to this file and I didn't get any error. What I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `file` parameter you supply to [/2/sharing/add_file_member](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-add_file_member) should be the `id` for the file for which you want to add a file member.

You can get the `id` for a file from the `Metadata` for the file, such as is returned by [/2/files/get_metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-get_metadata) or [/2/files/list_folder](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder)[[/continue]](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-list_folder-continue), for instance.

Also, note that [/2/sharing/add_file_member](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-add_file_member) uses [the RPC request/response style](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#rpc-endpoints), so your parameters should be sent as JSON in the request body, not a header.

In any case, make sure you check the resulting response status code and body to see if the call succeeded or failed, and to retrieve any returned result or error information.

Comment: i did  all these things but i m getting error like  body: 'Error in call to API function "files/get_metadata": request body: could not decode input as JSON'

Comment: That error indicates that the data you're sending in your request body isn't valid JSON. I recommend using an actual JSON builder to build the JSON, instead of trying to format it by hand.